# asp.net core 2.0: connString is incompatible with 'microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext' because it's a string. Anyway to make them compatible?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm changing a c# web app from ASP.Net core 1.x to ASP.Net core 2.0.

```
public class Greetcontext : DbContext
{
    public Greetcontext(string connString) : base(connString){}
}
```

In previous asp.net core 1.x, the above  used to run fine, but while changing into asp.net core 2.0, I'm running into a problem where connectionString cannot be a string because of Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore. Therefore, I changed into

```
public class Greetcontext : DbContext
{
    public Greetcontext(DbContextOptions<Greetcontext> connString) : base(connString){}
}
```

However, it's giving an error since the connString in appsettings.json is string, making it incompatible to each other. Is there anyway this can be compatible to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using EF Core 2.0 with ASP.NET core 2.0 you should configure EF as shown below:

```
services.AddDbContext<TecTacDbContext>(opts =>
{
    // This is how you get the connectionString from your appsettings
    opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TecTac"));
    opts.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
});
```

You can get more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db)

Seb